# Change foreground colour or files showing error in rsync log file

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to colour the file names that are logged with an error when using `rsync`.

One such file will be as follows

```
2022/12/07 21:33:49 [3672] WARNING: b2-infocs/unix-like/2006-hagan-gcc.pdf failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).
2022/12/07 21:37:12 [3672] >f..tp..... b2-infocs/unix-like/2006-hagan-gcc.pdf
2022/12/07 21:37:12 [3672] rsync: read errors mapping "/media/hagbard/hc1/b3-book/b2-infocs/unix-like/2006-hagan-gcc.pdf": Input/output error (5)
2022/12/07 21:37:12 [3672] WARNING: b2-infocs/unix-like/2007-thomas-ubuntu-linux.pdf failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).
2022/12/07 21:41:32 [3672] >f..tp..... b2-infocs/unix-like/2007-thomas-ubuntu-linux.pdf
2022/12/07 21:41:32 [3672] rsync: read errors mapping "/media/hagbard/hc1/b3-book/b2-infocs/unix-like/2007-thomas-ubuntu-linux.pdf": Input/output error (5)
2022/12/07 21:41:32 [3672] ERROR: b2-infocs/rudiments/2002-history-of-computers-p1.pdf failed verification -- update discarded.
2022/12/07 21:41:32 [3672] ERROR: b2-infocs/unix-like/1997-beck-linux-kernel.pdf failed verification -- update discarded.
2022/12/07 21:41:32 [3672] ERROR: b2-infocs/unix-like/2006-hagan-gcc.pdf failed verification -- update discarded.
2022/12/07 21:41:32 [3672] ERROR: b2-infocs/unix-like/2007-thomas-ubuntu-linux.pdf failed verification -- update discarded.
2022/12/07 21:41:32 [3672] sent 4,608,232,734 bytes  received 7,948 bytes  107,600.04 bytes/sec
2022/12/07 21:41:32 [3672] total size is 7,522,508,549  speedup is 1.63
```

Have made the following code to match `"fail"`, then try to change colour foreground.  The `regex` got to be much more involved to change the face of for instance `2007-thomas-ubuntu-linux.pdf`.

```
(defface rsync-lampfc
  '((t :foreground "red"))
  "Colour typeface for rsync errors in a log file.")

(defun rsync-failre ()
  (highlight-regexp "fail" 'rsync-lampfc 1))

(defun rsync-loger ()
  "Colourise errors on files in rsync log file."
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'hi-lock-mode-hook 'rsync-failre))
```

Is it possible to have a function that when I call it, does the colour change.  I do not understand the `hi-lock-mode-hook` well.  Would the colour change affect the buffer as soon as `hi-lock-mode` is enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colouring files in rsync log file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74975/colouring-files-in-rsync-log-file)

Comment: @Drew Um, this question (also from OP) does not have an answer that I can see.

Comment: @FranBurstall: I think you're saying that neither of the dups has an answer. That's correct. Dunno whether that means we can't close one of them (?).

Comment: Have closed the other